# How to specify a code module as the "Object Ref" parameter in VB.Net CallByName?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to call a public subroutine from a Windows form based on a string variable containing the name of the subroutine.  The subroutine is a procedure in a code module and works fine when called by using the procedure name directly.

The VB.net function CallByName should work, but I don't know how to specify the module name as the "Object Ref" parameter.

[image]

In the code shown, "ReportLibrary" is a module containing the public sub with the name contained in the string strReportProcedure.  This results in the following error helper:

[image]

The Help says this about the ObjectRef parameter:

> ObjectRef
>   Type: System.Object
>   Required. Object. A pointer to the object exposing the property or method.

What am I missing or is it just not possible to call a routine from a module using CallByName?

Answer (score 2):

[CallByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chsc1tx6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) will not work for code in VB.Net modules since the first parameter requires an object. You need to move the methods into a class, then create an instance of the class in order to make CallByName work.

Comment: Not an optimal way. In my case I can't move them, because there will be chaos after it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, I think the problem is somewhere else.
I think you haven't declared a variable like this:

```
Dim RL as NEW Reportlibrary
```

And after declaring it, use this:

```
CallByName(RL, strReportProcedure , CallType.Method , blnPreview)
```

Probably the problem was in declaration, because (in your case) your class doesn't let you access to your library's subroutines. That's why you need to declare "as New ReportLibrary".
Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

`Dim  object As NEW Reportlibrary` and then just use that Object.